# Why doesn't my batch program to mass search similar inquiries work?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code to mass search similar inquiries.

```
@echo off
title autosearcher
***:start***
set /p UserInputPath = Copy and Paste Here
set UserInputPath=%UserInputPath: =+%
start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=%UserInputPath% ***^***
***goto :start***
```

I have a text document with many lines that all start with the same sentence. I want my batch program to search the first line, then the second, etc. For whatever reason, when I ran the program, this is what I got:

```
A tab to google chrome home page.
A tab with the url as %3D+
A tab with the url as goto/
A tab with the url as start/
```

Also, I'm not sure that the with ***text*** is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What was "pasted" into the example when you ran the program? Also why are you setting UserInputPath after it was just set from the command prompt?

Comment: You got the tab with %3D+ because you misplaced the % on the second set of UserInputPath

Comment: Classic problem comes to mind immediately (btw - you can't decorate within a *code* block) - `set` is sensitive to spaces on **both** sides of the `=`, so your `set /p` is setting a variable named "UserInputPath[space]", not "UserInputPath"

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].  The batch code you posted can't possibly produce the output you claim.

Comment: @DanielGale I'm setting it again to replace the spaces with + characters.
Magoo Thank you, I'm very new to using batch and stack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with spaces and % etc. The path to chrome.exe may need to be given if it is not stored in your path.

```
@echo off
title autosearcher
:start

set /p UserInputPath=Enter your search term(s):
start "New Chrome Tab" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com#q=%UserInputPath%

goto :start
```